# Getting parse error while defining the html href tag in php

Tags: php, html

Can anybody help me out here? How can I write this correctly?

```
echo "<td><a type='button' href='patent_edit.php?id="$patent_id"' >Edit</a>;</td>";
```

I am  getting error that

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$patent_id' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\moduletwo\patent_view.php

Comment: ... `" . $patent_id . "` ...

Answer (score 0):

Error is at $patent_id you're not concatenating it right try this

```
 echo "<td><a type='button' href='patent_edit.php?id=".$patent_id."' >Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><a type='button' href='patent_edit.php?id=".$patent_id."' >Edit</a>;</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
echo "<td><a type='button' href='patent_edit.php?id="$patent_id"' >Edit</a>;</td>";
```

With

```
echo "<td><a type='button' href='patent_edit.php?id=".$patent_id."' >Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common syntax error. You are facing concatenation problem.

You can solve this by this:

```
echo "<td><a type='button' href='patent_edit.php?id=$patent_id' >Edit</a>;</td>";
```

or this

```
echo "<td><a type='button' href='patent_edit.php?id=".$patent_id."' >Edit</a>;</td>";
```